# How to cryptographically guarantee that data came from a trusted application on a mobile device?

Tags: digital-signature, opensource

I'd like to have an open source application generate data and sign it in such a way that anyone with access to the data alone can know for sure it was generated by that open source code.

More specifically the application runs on a mobile device, say Android, and is not a trusted party. It generates data by processing device's sensor readings like camera, gps, etc with an open source algorithm. The data is then presumibly signed and uploaded to a database.

The idea is that someone who gets access to the data (observer) can cryptographically confirm that it was generated by a known version of the open source application. The observer does not have access to the runtime environment.

Is it possible to ensure that the application is a known, official version, or is it possible to circumvent?

Comment: I've edited the questions to be more specific. In line with Steffen's comment, I can't figure out how to give the open source application access to a private key it can use to sign the data which is not also open to the world.

Comment: Zeroth Law of Computer Security -- if you don't control the platform, you can't control the software

Comment: Please note that in your description, it isn't necessary to reverse engineer/crack the key management or signature logic.  By having the generation of data separate from packaging/signature, you create a window where the data can be tampered.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not.

Data generated by a client can always be compromised. If the program can be accessed by an attacker, its secrets can be compromised. With the secrets, the attacker can generate data and sign it to make it look like data from your application.

Even if you encrypt, encode, obfuscate or protect the keys used to sign, those keys must be in clear during the sign process, and the attacker can grab those keys using a debugger or inspecting a memory dump.

He could use breakpoints on your application to suspend its execution right before the sign process, change the data and have the application sign it. He could extract the keys and reverse-engineer the application to create its own signing application.

The only way to guarantee that the data originates from your application is when you have control over the hardware and OS, and there's no way to the attacker to get a copy of your program nor execute its own applications. Running your application on your servers would solve it, but would be not practical for the majority of uses.

Answer (score 3):

You requirement has 2 major flaws:

1. it is not possible to securely include a secret in an application: by decompilation, the end user will always be able to find it. All you can do is *obfuscation* (google for it if you do not know).

   Best practices in security recommends that a *secret* is to be accessed by very few people (idealy one single owner). That way, if you can confirm that the secret has been used, you can assume that the data was produced by a secret owner. And everything that is not a secret should be assumed to be known by an attacker. That does not mean that is should be publicly known, but the security should not depend on it.

   In contrast, obfuscation consists in making something hard but not impossible to decode. It is often used in Javascript, because the script has to be interpretable by a browser, but some authors do not want that anyone can easily re-use their scripts. But if some one really wants to, it is always possible to understand what the script actually does.

   Even in the case of compiled software, it is always possible to run the software through a debugger to identify at what point the data is encrypted and how.
2. I am sorry but there is no point in it (except software royalties protection but that is not the right tool IMHO): what should matters is who sent the data, or at least what specific installation (what machine or group of machine) sent it.

   If you really want to know if the software was used by a legitimate user, each one should have a private key and the software should use that key

Comment: _Open-source_ sw mustn't be obfuscated. Although experience shows it can be so badly written it is very difficult to understand, which arguably accomplishes the same thing :}